# SWFObject and jQuery Lava Lamp plugin, Flash flickers in FF

Tags: jquery, flash, firefox, lavalamp

HI,

I have a flash movie and lavalamp menu on the page, when moving the mouse over the menu the flash flickers, and the lavalamp animation is slow and not smooth.

- SWFObject v2.2
- jQuery v1.5
- jquery.LavaLamp v1.3.5

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen issues like this related to the wmode param in the embed code. Experiment with setting it to the accepted values (eg. opaque, transparent, window).